Motion with parabolic blends problem. Seems easy but feels impossible!
I'm trying to calculate multi segment trajectories between points in a plane where the trajectory follows a linear function, but in order to keep continuous speed and position parabolic blends are introduced at the turns.
Like in the fiure below where the path goes from Point A to Point B to Point C but blends parabolically at B. Acceleration and speed are fixed.
My approach to calculate the blend is:

Determine the direction vectors $Dir_{AB}$ and $Dir_{BC}$
Make them unit length
Calculate the time, $\Delta T$, it will take to turn from $Dir_{AB}$ to $Dir_{BC}$ given the fixed acceleration and speed.
$$\Delta T =\frac{\Vert v(Dir_{BC}-Dir_{AB})\Vert}{a}=\frac{v}{a}\sqrt{2(1- Dir_{AB,x}Dir_{BC,x}+Dir_{AB,y}Dir_{BC,y})}$$
Calculate A', the point where blending starts by calculating backwards from B.
$$l = v\frac{\Delta T}{2}$$
$$A'=B-l Dir_{AB}$$
$$C'=B+l Dir_{BC}$$
The formula for calculating the position $p(t)$ during the blend can be derived as below:
$$a(t)=\frac{v(Dir_{BC}-Dir_{AB})}{\Delta T}$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$v(t)=\int a(t)dt=\frac{v(Dir_{BC}-Dir_{AB})}{\Delta T}t+M \qquad (t=0 \rightarrow M=v Dir_{AB})$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$p(t)=\int v(t)dt=\frac{v(Dir_{BC}-Dir_{AB})}{2\Delta T}t^2+v Dir_{AB}t+N \qquad (t=0 \rightarrow N=A')$$
This gives the parabola for the blend used between A' and C' as shown in Figure 1 above and more detailed in Figure 2 below. 

So far so good!
The problem arises when I reformulate the question so instead of knowing point A, B and C, I would like to calculate B when point A and C' are known together with $Dir_{BC}$.
Figure 3 below shows one example of the problem where A and C' are known but not the exact location of point B. $Dir_{BC}$ is along the y axis (0,1) (in this example) and the exact location of C is irelevant since it does not affect the parabolic blend or B.
Just by looking at Figure 3 I think it is obvious that if speed and acceleration are fixed and known there can be only one solution to the problem and it must then be possible to calculate the location of B. I have not been able to solve it however, no matter how hard I try. Since I don't know $Dir_{AB}$ I just end up in frustrating loops. I'd guess that I'm overlooking something, possibly, obvious. Perhaps there is some fancy property of parabolas that could be used?

I'm not just skilled enough...
Some updates based on comments ____________________________________
This is about creating a motion trajectory in cartesian space and I have got heavily inspired by Robotic Path Planning and especially  these lecture notes by Prof. Alessandro De Luca where parabolic bends (or blends) are used although circular ones are also mentioned.
A parabolic bend should be tighter than a circular one given the same acceleration and speed (right?).
When planning a multi point trajectory the intermediate "via-points" will never be exactly passed but rather overflown with some distance, as Point B in the Figures above. My problem is that I sometimes have viapoints that must be passed exactly and also be at the extent of the movement area in the "x-direction". So at this point the x velocity should be zero and changing from positive to negative.
The Figure below shows an example of such a movement from P1 to P2 passing point FP exactly. The green trace shows a circular bend and and the orange shows a parabolic one (same accelleration and speed in both cases). As can be seen the parabolic is tighter than the circular one. P1, P2 and FP are known, T1 and T2 (where circular accelleration starts and ends) can be calculated but I and L are almost impossible, (sorry for changing notation!)

Is there an easy way to solve this, like adding other viapoints that ensures a perfect crossing of FP (without overshoot)?

Why parabolic? Why not circular arcs? And if velocity is known and "fixed," how can you not know the direction from $A$ to $B$? Or did you mean "speed" when you wrote "velocity"? Note that your assumptions in constructing your parabola also imply that speed will vary during the turn.

You are right, I mean speed, not velocity. I'm not in my native language here...
Circular arcs would be easier since the problem boils down to just trigonometry but I wanted parabolic blends to keep all movements within the convex hull of the points.
Will speed really vary, isn't it just the velocity that changes?

You are using the equations for a free-falling body. Nothing wrong if you like it, but speed is definitely not constant. It's only the projection of velocity perpendicular to the axis of the parabola which is constant.

But I will exit the parabola with the same speed, v, as I entered. Othervise the calculation of $\Delta T$ will be different.

The picture looks so reminiscent of Bezier splines that I would be a little bit surprised if they weren't a better tool for the underlying job than this idea.

The way I see it is that I have acceleration in the fixed direction DirBC-DirAB (hence the parabolic curve) for the exact time that is needed to reduce the velocity in the AB direction and increase the velocity in the BC direction so that the exit speed is the same as the entrance speed. Is this not true?

Your kinematic is correct, as I wrote above. What about my answer?

Never mind, I see how it works now. It seems like a sorta weird scenario physically to me, but I get it anyway.

Your exit speed is the same as your entrance speed with your particular kind of parabolic arc, but the speeds when you are between the ends of the arc are slower. You lose speed for the first half of the arc and then spend the second half getting back up to speed. A circular arc is constant-speed with constant magnitude of acceleration and is even easier to insert into a trajectory like this than the parabolic arc is. I can't imagine why you think that would cause any difficulty in keeping the path within the convex hull of the points.

You are right, of course. It is certainly possible to do a circular blend within the convex hull of the points. The reason why I ended up with the parabolic approach that I have presented is that I got inspired by "Trajectory Planning" in robotics where "parabolic blends at via points" seems very common. What are the benefits with a parabolic path compared to a circular one at the via points?

Honestly I have no idea why robotics planners would choose parabolic blends for a path in space. If the robot is changing speed between two segments then it makes sense to blend the speed with a parabola (plotted on a time-vs.-distance plot), but the axis of the parabola is perpendicular to the distance axis, not bisecting the angle between segments (which isn't really meaningful on that plot anyway). If you're piloting a space vehicle in free fall then any single rocket burn will give you a parabolic path unless you rotate during the burn.

@DavidK One reason for parabolic bends could be that it is a tighter turn compared to a circular one given the same acceleration and speed.
I'll update the question with some more information.

The OP wants to connect two straight paths $AA'$ and $C'C$, run at constant speed,  via a curved path $A'C'$, obtained by imposing that acceleration on the curve be constant and perpendicular to line $A'C'$. This leads to a parabolic arc $A'C'$. The magnitudes of speed and acceleration are fixed and given. The problem is that of finding $A'$, given the positions of $A$, $C'$ and $C$. This is equivalent to finding $B$, the intersection of $AA'$ and $C'C$.
Note first of all that from the kinematic exposed in the question one gets:
$$
A'B=C'B=l={v^2\over a}\sin{\theta\over2},
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between vectors $\vec{}$ and $\vec{}$.
Draw from $A$ draw a line perpendicular to $CC'$, intersecting it at $H$. Set: $AH=d$, $C'H=h$ and $BH=x$.
We have then the following equations, to solve for $x$ and $\theta$:
$$
\cases{
x=d\cot\theta\\
\\
\displaystyle h-x={v^2\over a}\sin{\theta\over2}
}
$$
Eliminating $x$ is easy, but the resulting equation for $\theta$ is quite nasty and leads to a sixth-degree algebraic equation, judging at least from the result I got using Mathematica.


How do you get $l=\frac{v^2}{a}sin\frac{\theta}{2}$?  I'm to tired to get it.  :)

$$||{}−{}||=\sqrt{2-2\cos\theta}=\sqrt{4\sin^2(\theta/2)}$$

Ah, I got it. Beautiful, really nice spotted!  But it doesn't seem to help me if I end up with a beasty sixth-degree equation. I'm amazed that this is so hard!

@Quist This answer incorporates some beastly constraints that you seem to have put on the problem. In addition to equal, predetermined speeds before and after the turn (which is quite reasonable), you've specified that the acceleration has to come from a constant direction (which is very strange unless this is a rocket burn in free fall) and you allow no choice in the magnitude of acceleration, only the direction. [to be continued...]

[... continuing] It's also reasonable to say that the path should go straight from $C'$ to $C,$ but what I suspect really makes things complicated is that you require that the curved part of the path must meet the straight part exactly at $C'$ and not even the tiniest distance before.

@DavidK I have explained the rationale to my constraints a little bit further by updating my Question.
